# set active class in navbar with jquery even its not child link

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, yii2

Here is my html code from single-product.html

```
<nav class="main-navi">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="index.html">
                Home
                <span class="dot"></span>
                <span class="corner"></span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="portfolio.html">
                Portfolio
                <span class="dot"></span>
                <span class="corner"></span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="about.html">
                About
                <span class="dot"></span>
                <span class="corner"></span>
            </a>
        </li>

        <li>
            <a href="service.html">
                services
                <span class="dot"></span>
                <span class="corner"></span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="blog.html">
                Blog
                <span class="dot"></span>
                <span class="corner"></span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="contact.html">
                contacts
                <span class="dot"></span>
                <span class="corner"></span>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <em id="showHideMenu" class="show-hide-menu fa fa-bars" href="#"></em>
</nav>


<p>lorem ipsum bla bla bla bla bla bla blabla </p>
```

so my question: as you can see in navbar i didnt put single-portfolio1, single-profolio2 and single-portfolio3 in navbar. so i want when i load single-portfolio1 or 2 or 3, iwant in navbar the portfolio link got class acitve. How can I do that with jquery? Can I set with specific approach like contain("single-portfolio").

Comment: jQuery's `attr()` gets the attribute, so what you're getting is just `portfolio.html`, and that clearly doesn't match what you see in the adress bar of the browser, which is probably more like `http://www.example.com/portfolio.html` etc. Try using `this.href` which gets the property, and will be an absolute URL, but generally setting classes based on URL is not a very good idea.

Comment: i try your script and it work awesome. but when i open the single-portfolio-1.html, portfolio link on navbar still didnt have active class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there are a couple of different ways you can approach this.  First you could create an array of pages that you want the active class to be displayed on and then if the `window.location.pathname` is in this array you could fire the active class like so:

```
var pageArray = ["/single-portfolio-1.html", "/single-portfolio-2.html", "/single-portfolio-3.html"];
var loc = window.location.pathname;
if ($.inArray(loc, pageArray) >  -1){
     $('.main-navi ul li a[href="portfolio.html"]').addClass("active");
}
```

Remember this will look for the pathname of the page so if your url is example.com/single-portfolio-1.html it will return /single-portfolio-1.html if it is example.com/pages/single-portfolio-1.html it will return /pages/single-portfolio-1.html so adjust this accordingly in your array

Or you could find something that has a class unique to these pages or give the body on these pages a class and then fire your active class if an element on your single portfolio pages `hasClass()` like so:

```
if($('body').hasClass("portfolio-page")){
    $('.main-navi ul li a[href="portfolio.html"]').addClass("active");
}
```

If you have an element that is unique to your single portfolio pages you can use that just replace the if statement to include the unique element.

or you can just place a script on these pages to change the active class like so:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('.main-navi ul li a[href="portfolio.html"]').addClass("active");
});
```

Hopefully this helps

Comment: sorry not work when i open single-portfolio1.html. portfolio link in navbar still didnt have class active

Comment: Oh my bad I think I read the question wrong do you want to add the active class to both the main nav and the single portfolio nav if the location matches or just the single portfolio nav

Comment: i only want if i go to single-portfolio1.html or single-portfolio2.html or single-portfolio3.html,  then in navbar, the portfolio link will have class active because in navbar im not including single-portfolio1.html or single-portfolio2.html or single-portfolio3.html. any way i use contain in jquery?? in single_portfolio1 or 2 or 3jtml. i have navbar too. and i need  portfolio link in that navbar will show up

Comment: sir my deeply apology. i have update my code. my bad. so i want the jquery check the url and if the url contain single-portfolio. the portfolio link on navbar in (only for page single-portfolio1.html,single-portfolio2.html, and single-portfolio3.html)has active class.

Comment: Are you loading these pages by ajax it would make more sense just to add the active class manually to these pages then when these pages load they will have the active class there already

Comment: im displaying by php sir with yii framework sir. honestly i looping the navbar for every page. so i cant make a different code's navbar

Comment: the champ is here, your sir so pro. thanks you solve my 5 hours problem. thanks sir